# Как вывести из базы заданное кол-во новостей?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Купил самописную cms, нужно вывести 5 новостей из базы, а выводятся все ~300

**Код вывода**:

```
$db_news = new DataBase(__DIR__.'/db_news.txt');

$items = $db_news->all();

foreach ($items as $item)
```

У каждой новости свой id

То, что в базе:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id":1,
        "title":"заголовок",
        "description":"описание",

    }
    ,
    "7": {
        "id":7,
        "title":"заголовок",
        "description":"описание",

    }
    ,
    "12": {
        "id":12,
        "title":"заголовок",
        "description":"описание",

    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите ограничить вывод 5 новостями.

У меня получилось сделать так:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($items as $item){
    // тут вывод
    if (++$count >= 5)
        break;
}
```

но так я получаю все новости, а использую только 5...

И еще, из-за чего вывод новостей может быть разбросан т.е. не по порядку?
Пример: 1, 12, 7 - как это исправить в моем выводе?

Спасибо!

Comment: А вы у класса `DataBase` все доступные методы посмотрели? Кроме `$db_news->all();` должно же ещё что-то быть в это чудо движке :)

Comment: Ну а то, что не по порядку — это нужно смотреть логику записи в эту чудо-базу данных.

Comment: $db_news->all(); нет ничего больше   :(

Comment: И класс `DataBase` больше ни от какого класса не наследуется и/или другие «магические» способы вызов методов не имеет? Тогда нужно дополнительные методы создавать в классе, которые решали бы ваши задачи по аналогии `[LIMIT [offset,] rows]`. Можно через выборку `$items = $db_news->all();` сделать, пропустив N-количество записей, но лучше через метод, потому что мало ли где вы его повторно будете использовать.

Comment: Исходный код класса `DataBase` сильно большой? Можете его в вопрос добавить? Думаю в этом нет ничего криминального, наврядли кто это захочит где-нибудь воспроизводить :) Может быть я или кто-нибудь другой найдет время медот нужный для вас добавить. Но нужно исходик класса.

Comment: `Купил самописную cms` где новости хранятся в текстовом файле. `рукалицо.жпг`